# Am I doing dependency injection in activity code correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, testing, android-activity, dependency-injection

I am currently coding my first android project, which I want to refactor according to the dependency injection pattern. Starting with the easiest activity in my app - the splash screen - I'm asking myself, if I understood the idea of the pattern correctly.

This is the code of my `SplashActivity` so far:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Fragment fragmentToDisplay = null;
        if (!(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isLaunch", true))) {
            fragmentToDisplay = new LoginFragment();
        } else {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                fragmentToDisplay = new SplashFragment();
            }
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToDisplay).commit();
    }
}
```

Depending on the content of the IntentExtra `"isLaunch"` I want to display a different fragment. Now, I have read that every `new ServiceXY()` makes the code less testable, which is actually not the target of dependency injection. So I refactored my code like so:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SplashFragment splashFragment;
    private LoginFragment loginFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();

        Fragment fragmentToDisplay = null;
        if (!(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isLaunch", true))) {
            fragmentToDisplay = loginFragment;
        } else {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                fragmentToDisplay = splashFragment;
            }
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToDisplay).commit();
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to make much of a difference. How does this improve the testability of my code, if I want to test, if the correct fragment gets displayed? Thanks in forward.

Comment: "I have read that every new ServiceXY() makes the code less testable" Where have you read this? I think, that the testability gets better, because of the available reference for the fragments (refactored code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your change does not make much of a difference and is not injecting the dependency. Since your SplashActivity object is responsible for creating the fragments, they are still dependent on the SplashActivity object.

If you want to use dependency injection, you would have to create the fragment objects somewhere outside the SplashActivity and then pass them into the object.

Following the dependency injection principle, your service would be the fragment type, the client that uses the service would be the SplashActivity, and therefore you need another object that will "inject" the correct service into the client. https://stackify.com/dependency-injection/

You could use the code from the first snippet but instead of checking the boolean in the oncreate to set the correct fragment type, you could just simply pass in the fragment object into the splashactivity class and go `fragmentToDisplay = fragmentPassedIntoClass`. Then you could test if the fragment passed into the class is the correct type, and if the transaction begun properly. The injector would be responsbile for passing the correct `fragmentPassedIntoClass`

```
MainFragment fragment;
if(splash){ fragment = new SplashFragment(); }
if(login){fragment = new LoginFragment(); }

// Pass fragment variable into splash activity
SplashActivity activty = new SplashActivity(fragment);

public class SplashActivity{
    MainFragment mFragment;

    public SplashActivty(MainFragment fragment){
        mFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I got a bit off the track. So I have to pass the two fragment instances to the activity by an "injector"? Which would be a good practice and in which method in particular? I assume, that using an activity constructor is not a good approach.

Comment: You want to use either LoginFragment OR SplashFragment right? So you would create a base class, something like "MainFragment" and then LoginFragment and SplashFragment would derive from this base class. So then if your activity has an object of type MainFragment, you can pass it either a SplashFragment OR a LoginFragment and have that be stored in the same MainFragment variable.

For injection, take a look at the examples in this code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: I added really simple example to my original post for the basic idea. In this case, type MainFragment is synonymous with type "Fragment" that you use in your original code

Comment: Lucky shot, that the two fragments already have a common superclass :D. I changed my Activity a bit according to your tip and the tests still works schwifty. Thank you (I still have a little workaround for passing the initial fragment to my activity but I'm on the right track now :))